# EF Core 3.1 Client Side Evaluation Issue With Boolean Async Call

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core-3.1

I am migrating form .Net 2.1 to 3.1 and this is including EF Core upgrade.

Now I had LINQ query as following, that worked with no issues:

```
var application = await _db.CustomerApplications
                .AsNoTracking()
                .Include(i => i.CustomerApplicationFields)
                .Include(i => i.Customer)
                .Where(x => x.Customer.PublicId == formId && x.IsPublished) // Also tried with &
                .OrderByDescending(o => o.Version)
                .FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

With EF Core 3.1 I get error:

```
The LINQ expression 'DbSet<CustomerApplication>
    .Where(c => !(c.Deleted))
    .Join(
        outer: DbSet<Customer>
            .Where(c0 => !(c0.Deleted)), 
        inner: c => EF.Property<Nullable<long>>(c, "CustomerId"), 
        outerKeySelector: c0 => EF.Property<Nullable<long>>(c0, "Id"), 
        innerKeySelector: (o, i) => new TransparentIdentifier<CustomerApplication, Customer>(
            Outer = o, 
            Inner = i
        ))
    .Where(c => c.Inner.PublicId == __formId_0 && c.Outer.IsPublished)' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to either AsEnumerable(), AsAsyncEnumerable(), ToList(), or ToListAsync(). See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.
```

When I convert this query as following, then it works (moving `bool` evaluation outside):

```
var application = await _db.CustomerApplications
                .AsNoTracking()
                .Include(i => i.CustomerApplicationFields)
                .Include(i => i.Customer)
                .Where(x => x.Customer.PublicId == formId)
                .OrderByDescending(o => o.Version)
                .ToListAsync();

var result = application.FirstOrDefault(x => x.IsPublished);
```

Could someone explain to me, why this is an issue? I also tried `x.IsPublished == true`, which had no effect. This seems to be quite random.

I also tried with `AsTracking()`.

Comment: Did you try && instead of &?

Comment: I have tried both

Comment: What is `IsPublished`? is this a stored property or something caulculated (e.g. `IsPublished => PublishDate > DateTime.UtcNow`)?

Comment: It is calculated yes `[NotMapped] public bool IsPublished => PublishDate.HasValue;`. And it works, if I use directly `PublishDate.HasValue` ... Is there a workaround for that or do I need to use direct evaluation?

Comment: @Taurib You should try direct evaluation to see if it helps

Comment: This issue is directly called out in the EF Core 3.0 release notes. Why didn't you read them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before EF Core 3.0, queries that could not be translated into SQL queries were evaluated on the client side. This behaviour was dismissed and an exception is thrown instead of evaluating non-translatable queries on the client side, now.

Also I think the new behaviour should not lead to any big performance issues when you write **var result = application.FirstOrDefault(x => x.IsPublished);** separately, because the same thing happened before. It was just not visible before. (Please correct me if this assumption is wrong!)

Also you can try following if you want to have one query (did not test this):

```
var application = await _db.CustomerApplications
            .AsNoTracking()
            .Include(i => i.CustomerApplicationFields)
            .Include(i => i.Customer)
            .Where(x => x.Customer.PublicId == formId)
            .OrderByDescending(o => o.Version)
            .FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.IsPublished);
```

You can read about it in detail here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-3.0/breaking-changes#linq-queries-are-no-longer-evaluated-on-the-client

Comment: Thanks for your answer and explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You should use && instead of & or you can add another where clause.

Comment: I updated my question, I missed one `&` in there. By default I use `&&`